# ROSLaunch: [] is neither a launch file in package [] nor is [] a launch file name

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new ROS user. I've already installed the OS, but when I type "roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch --screen" it gives me an error.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark (amd64)

This is coppied from my terminal:

```
sgzhelev@Lenovo-Legion-Y520-15IKBN:~$ roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch --screen

RLException: [minimal.launch] is neither a launch file in package [kobuki_node] nor is [kobuki_node] a launch file name

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Thank you for all advices!

-- Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306900/roslaunch:-%5B%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5B%5D-nor-is-%5B%5D-a-launch-file-name/) by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:
First thing to check: have you `source`d the correct `setup.bash` before trying to run `roslaunch` like this?

Additionally: did you install the kobuki packages from sources (ie: did you have to run `catkin_make` first) or did you use `apt-get install ..`?

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
Yes, I have sourced the bash file and I used apt-get install, not catkin_make.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:
Then do you have the `kobuki` packages installed? They do not come with a default installation.

What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep kobuki` (add that to your original question, use the `edit` button/link)?

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
I will try that later because now I'm trying with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and ROS Kinetic.

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
When I type  `dpkg -l | grep kobuki`  the terminal is not showing anything. It's going on new row and waiting for a new command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I should've paid more attention:

> I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark (amd64)

together with the `Melodic` tag and:

> I used apt-get install [..]

is the cause here.

None of the Kobuki packages have been released as binaries for ROS Melodic yet.

Unless things have changed very recently, you'll need to build all of the turtlebot (2) stack from source on Melodic. That is possible, but you can/may run into some issues while doing that (see #q305453 for a recent Q&A about that).

The simple packages (such as `kobuki_description`) will build without issues, but as ROS Melodic uses Gazebo 9 (instead of Gazebo 7), you'll run into issues getting things like `kobuki_gazebo_plugins` to build.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
Yesterday, I have tried to install ROS from source, but Ubuntu freezed, maybe is becouse, like you said  Melodic is not finished yet. Now I'm trying with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and ROS Kinetic, because at school I have successfully installed it on 16.04.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:\

> I have tried to install ROS from source, but Ubuntu freezed, maybe is becouse, like you said Melodic is not finished yet.

No, that is most likely not the cause.

The base Melodic release is "finished", it's just that not all packages available in Kinetic are available on Melodic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:\

> Now I'm trying with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and ROS Kinetic

So do you have Melodic or Kinetic installed?

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
I've got two laptops. The first is with Ubuntu 17.10 and Melodic and the second is with 16.04 and Kinetic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:
Final comment: try to always use binary packages when installing ROS. Installing from source is almost never necessary or desirable.

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
Thanks for the answers but do you know where is located the log file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:
Which log file?

**Comment by [sgzhelev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38235/sgzhelev/) on 2018-10-28**:
Never mind... It all works now. I just had to install node... Thanks for your help and have a nice day!